# how to turn <path d=""> to button/hyperlink?

Tags: html, hyperlink, path

I have this piece of code here,

```
 <path d="M439.296,84.91c-1.024,0-2.56-0.512-4.096-0.512H112.64l-5.12-34.304C104.448,27.566,84.992,10.67,61.952,10.67H20.48 C9.216,10.67,0,19.886,0,31.15c0,11.264,9.216,20.48,20.48,20.48h41.472c2.56,0,4.608,2.048,5.12,4.608l31.744,216.064 c4.096,27.136,27.648,47.616,55.296,47.616h212.992c26.624,0,49.664-18.944,55.296-45.056l33.28-166.4 C457.728,97.71,450.56,86.958,439.296,84.91z"  />
```

and it is supposed to show an Icon, how can I turn it  to a hyperlink/button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the `<path>` inside an `<a>` tag.
Example:

```
<a href="link">
    <path d="…">
</a>
```

If you want to use a button use a `<button>` tag

Than  you need to disable the underline with this css rule: `text-decoration:none` You can apply that directly inside the `<a>` tag: `<a href="link" style="text-decoration:none">`